# Why is my hfs partition suddenly mounting read-only, with no way to alter it to read-write?

Tags: mount, permissions, hfs+

I am backing up my FreeNAS volume onto a partition of an external WD 4TB My Book, which uses the hfs filesystem and is mounted on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04.  Each time the drive is mounted, all partitions are mounted read-only.  I have tried:

1. Turning off journaling via Terminal on a Mac machine.
2. Installing `hfsprogs` and remounting the volume using

   `sudo mount -t hfsplus -o remount,force,rw /dev/sdb2 /media/mntpoint`
3. Changing permissions of all volume contents using `chmod`

This worked, and I was able to write to and delete from the mounted volume.  Then, suddenly the problem returned, and the above solution no longer worked.  I was able to write to the volume, but not delete anything, either using `rsync` or `rm`.

I ran `sudo dmesg | tail`, which gave the output:

```
[  109.876362] hfsplus: Filesystem was not cleanly unmounted, running fsck.hfsplus is recommended.  mounting read-only.
```

Inputting `mount | grep /dev/sdb2` also indicated that it was mounted ro:

```
/dev/sdb2 on /media/mntpoint1 type hfsplus (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,umask=22,uid=0,gid=0,nls=utf8,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Running `sudo fsck.hfsplus /dev/sdb2` indicated a problem with the volume:

```
** /dev/sdb2
** Checking HFS Plus volume.
** Checking Extents Overflow file.
** Checking Catalog file.
** Checking Catalog hierarchy.
** Checking Extended Attributes file.
   Keys out of order
(8, 3)
** Repairing volume.
** Rechecking volume.
** Checking HFS Plus volume.
** Checking Extents Overflow file.
** Checking Catalog file.
** Checking Catalog hierarchy.
** Checking Extended Attributes file.
   Keys out of order
(8, 3)
** Repairing volume.
** Rechecking volume.
** Checking HFS Plus volume.
** Checking Extents Overflow file.
** Checking Catalog file.
** Checking Catalog hierarchy.
** Checking Extended Attributes file.
   Keys out of order
(8, 3)
** Repairing volume.
** Rechecking volume.
** Checking HFS Plus volume.
** Checking Extents Overflow file.
** Checking Catalog file.
** Checking Catalog hierarchy.
** Checking Extended Attributes file.
   Keys out of order
(8, 3)
** The volume Volume Name could not be repaired after 3 attempts.
```

Moving back to my Mac, I ran Disk Utility, and none of the partitions appeared to be mounted.  I ran Verify Disk which found errors and suggested Repair Disk, which successfully repaired the volume, and subsequently all other partitions appeared as mounted and OK.

Moving back to Ubuntu, `mount | grep /dev/sdb2` now gives:

```
/dev/sdb2 on /media/mntpoint1 type hfsplus (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,umask=22,uid=0,gid=0,nls=utf8,uhelper=udisks2)
```

indicating that it is mounted rw.  I was then able to delete files with `rw`, and `rsync` could write to the volume.

After a few days (and I don't know what changed) I have since lost the ability to delete files with `rw`, `rsync` has decided to delete the majority of the files on the target volume at random, and I cannot write to the volume.  Running `sudo dmesg | tail` now gives, one of the following two outputs for each of the mounted partitions (I'm not sure which is the volume in question):

```
[133264.935495] hfsplus: filesystem was not cleanly unmounted, running fsck.hfsplus is recommended.  leaving read-only.
[133274.501698] hfsplus: walked past end of dir
```

Finally, running `sudo fsck.hfsplus /dev/sdb2` gives the same output as previously, failing to repair the volume after 3 attempts.

As a novice, I'm at a total loss.  Help me Ask Ubuntu, you're my only hope.

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: Seems like you might have a hardware problem. Have you tried checking [the SMART status](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools)?